# Expo-camera doesn't detects faces with eas builds, works well on expo go

Tags: react-native, expo, eas, expo-camera

Expo camera's property onFaceDetected doesn't gets triggered while testing with eas builds like expo-dev-client or apk files using EAS cli. It works fine on Expo Go. But when using eas builds, it results in no response from onFaceDetected property. Tried different versions of libraries but this issue still persist.

Managed or bare workflow?
managed

What platform(s) does this occur on?
Android

Package versions

```
"expo": "\~48.0.16",
"expo-status-bar": "\~1.4.4",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.71.7",
"expo-camera": "\~13.2.1",
"expo-dev-client": "\~2.2.1",
"expo-face-detector": "\~12.1.1"
```

Environment

```
System:
OS: Windows 10 10.0.22621
Binaries:
Node: 18.16.1 - C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.EXE
npm: 9.6.6 - C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\npm.CMD
IDEs:
Android Studio: AI-222.4459.24.2221.9971841
npmPackages:
expo: \~48.0.16 =\> 48.0.19
react: 18.2.0 =\> 18.2.0
react-native: 0.71.7 =\> 0.71.7
Expo Workflow: managed
```

Reproducible demo
https://github.com/mudassir-rafiq-007/camera-face-detection.git

Stacktrace (if a crash is involved)
No response

Tried different versions of libraries but this issue still persist.